# Marginal density and probability from Joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am struggling with two particular issues with this problem, one being the support since I always get confused with indicator functions and the other being the particular part were we have $I_{(0,1)} (x+y)$. The problem goes thus:

Joint pdf of X and Y is given by:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3(x+y)I_{(0,1)} (x+y)I_{(0,1)} (x)I_{(0,1)} (y).$$

1. Derive the marginal density of X.
2. What is $P(X+Y <0.5)?$
3. Find $ E(Y|X=x)$

My attempt is to try to get rid of the indicator functions and rewrite the joint pdf as

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3(x+y),  \ \ \ \ \ \ \     0<x+y<1, \ 0<x<1, \ 0<y<1$$

and then attempt to solve as follows:

1. Marginal density of X

$\ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ f(x) = \int_0^1 3(x+y) dy = 3(xy + \frac{y^2}{2} \Big|_0^1 =3(x + \frac{1}{2})$

2. For $P(X+Y <0.5)$, I have no idea how to go about this. I assume we have to write one variable in terms of the other e.g. $0<x<1-y$ and then use this in the support?
3. For $ E(Y|X=x)$, do i need to find the marginal density of y as done for x in (a)?

Am I on the right path? Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the condition that $x+y<1$ or $y <1-x$. The correct marginal is $f(x)=\int_0^{1-x} 3(x+y)dy=\frac {3(1-x^{2})} 2, 0<x<1$.

$$P(X+Y<0.5)=\iint_{(x,y): x+y <0.5}  f(x,y)dydx $$ $$=\int_0^{1}\int_0^{0.5-x} 3(x+y)dydx.$$ I will let you finish.